# query to select data from this day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database table that has `Datelogged` columns from type `Datetime` (Sql server 2008 r2)

The Datelogged value is like this `2014-10-22 12:57:36.583`

I want to do a query to select all the rows that its date is today (I care about year, month, and day) but not (hour, second.)

This is my query

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE PrintTime is NULL WHERE Datelogged = @Datelogged";
```

but I didn't know what should I do to tell the query to compare just on year-month-day

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Query is not correct. Two where clauses present in the query. Second where will be an 'and' operator i think. Please correct it.

Comment: `WHERE DateLogged >= CONVERT(DATE, @DateLogged) AND DateLogged < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, @DateLogged));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Aaron Bertrand [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533776/query-to-select-data-from-this-day/26533900#comment41694189_26533900)

It appears that it is better to use a Date Range from current day midnight (00:00:00) to < tomorrow at midnight.

Query copied from [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533776/query-to-select-data-from-this-day/26533900#comment41694281_26533776).

```
DateLogged >= CONVERT(DATE, @DateLogged) AND 
DateLogged < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, @DateLogged))
```

Also see: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries By Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

---

(Old Answer)

You can use `CONVERT(DATE, Datelogged)` to get Date part without time.

```
"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE PrintTime is NULL AND CONVERT(DATE, Datelogged) = @Datelogged"
```

Make sure you pass the parameter value using `Date` property in C# like:

```
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@Datelogged", DateTime.Today);// or DateTime.Now.Date
```

Also make sure to remove multiple `WHERE` from your query and use `AND` or `OR` to combine two conditions depending on your requirement.

Comment: Open-ended range (>= today at midnight and < tomorrow at midnight) is much better. [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: @Marco [please be sure to read the link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea) and also read this post for information about proper date range queries: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that is interesting, never knew about it. I am pretty sure I have used it in production, and would be looking to change it now. Thanks for the useful links.

Answer (score 1):

Get the minimum date time range for current date and maximum date time range for today. Then, compare it with the logged date value.

Conversion operator on any table column adds extra conversion overhead and leads to inefficient use of index. Should be avoided when possible.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders 
WHERE PrintTime is NULL 
AND (Datelogged   > dateadd(DD, -1, cast( GETDATE() as date)) AND Datelogged   < dateadd(DD, 1, cast( GETDATE() as date)));
```

Comment: Open-ended range (>= today at midnight and < tomorrow at midnight) is much better. [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, You are right it will have conversion overhead and will be less searchable due to presence of conversion operation. I have updated my answer.

Thanks for reminding :)